# Sorting agGrid By a GroupBy Autocolumn When Saving/Restoring Column State

Tags: javascript, sorting, ag-grid

In our application using agGrid, we allow the user to provide a default sort which is then passed into our screen upon opening, converted into an agGrid sort model, and then passed to agGrid to set the sort model (api.setSortModel).

Since the columns on this screen are known, it is easy to specify something like CCYID ASC, ENTITYID DESC and have it be directly translated into a sort model.

However the problem is that some of these screens use row grouping.  In this particular instance we're grouping by CCYID.  The actual CCYID column is then set to hidden and the groupby values are displayed in an agGrid automatically generated column (the autocolumn I believe?)

However,  I still want to sort by CCYID, but as it is a hidden column, no sort will take.  Is there a way to specify the auto column by name such that it could be used in defining a sort model?  Does it have a constant name, something like "AUTOCOLUMN0" or some such?